# Resend verification email in Django using Django-Verify-Email

Tags: python, django, email-verification

I am using Django-Verify-Email 1.0.6 in order to verify my email address.

I verified my email using this function:
`send_verification_email(request, form)`

if the user verifies its email then it fine. The problem arises when the email link gets expired and the user needs to verify email by resending the email.

This package contain a function `resend_verification_email(request, encoded_email, encoded_token)`

the description of the function says to pass **encoded_email** and **encoded_token** which was generated previously.

I don't think whether our system has that encoded_token and encoded_email save in DB. Can anyone help me with how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess here goes my first ever answer on Stack Overflow.

After I found this post I continued trying to look for a solution, and found it here: https://github.com/foo290/Django-Verify-Email/issues/6#issuecomment-782689288

While the post is certainly revealing, simply copy pasting the code did not work. So here is what I did in detail.

Firstly you need to extend the class:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.mail import BadHeaderError
from smtplib import SMTPException
from django.utils.html import strip_tags


class VerifyEmail(_VerifyEmail):
    def send_verification_link(self, request, user):
        try:
            useremail = user.email
            verification_url = self.token_manager.generate_link(request, user, useremail)

            subject = self.settings.get("subject")
            msg = render_to_string(
                self.settings.get("html_message_template", raise_exception=True),
                {"link": verification_url},
            )

            try:
                send_mail(
                    subject,
                    strip_tags(msg),
                    from_email=self.settings.get("from_alias"),
                    recipient_list=[useremail],
                    html_message=msg,
                )
                return user
            except (BadHeaderError, SMTPException):
                # user.delete()
                return False

        except Exception as error:
            # user.delete()
            if self.settings.get("debug_settings"):
                raise Exception(error)
```

As you can see the method requires a request object. That is actually essential, as it is used to generate the link. The quickest way to do this then is to actually create a view. The following sample is more or less the page I needed - I had to find a way to verify and activate all the users that are not activated yet (we were not activating them at all before this), so what the script does is cycle through all the User objects marked as inactive and send the verification email:

```
from django.views import View
from VerifyEmail import VerifyEmail
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseForbidden

class VerifyInactiveUsersSender(View):

    def get(self, request):
        if(request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser):
            inactive_users = User.objects.filter(is_active=False)
            for u in inactive_users:
                inactive_user = VerifyEmail().send_verification_link(request, u)

            return HttpResponse("Go check")
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Given this code sends an email to all the inactive accounts I needed to add the security check, `if(request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser):`, but that is not needed at all for simply creating a form where the user can get a second email. Hope this helps anybody.